# How do I access data from a JSON file in Ruby tests?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems, ruby-test

I have a JSON file:

```
{
  "user": "John",
  "first": "John",
  "last": "Wilson",
  "updated": "2013-02-17",
  "generated_at": "2013-02-13",
  "version": 1.1,
}
```

I want to use this as the data file for my Ruby test and want to access the data in this file.  I am doing the data verification as:

```
application[data_first]. should eq 'John'
```

I want to refer to the expected data from the JSON file using something like:

```
application[data_first]. should eq JSON_file[first]
```

Assuming the JSON file's name is "JSON_file", I also have added `require 'JSON_file'` at the top of my test script.

How do I access the data from JSON file?

Comment: Have you tried the [standard JSON library](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html)?

Comment: Okies I figured it out...

data = JSON.parse(File.read(file_path of JSON_file)) and then data['first'] gives the value of first name.